# How do we advertise math.SE?

Tags: discussion

We all presumably came here after receiving the email that math.SE was in private beta. In a few days, however, the site will go public.  We'd like to get a much bigger following, and I doubt we'll show up at the top of Google results until the site has expanded.

So, how do we attract more people to this site?

Comment: Tell your friends!!! That's what I have been doing :D

Comment: I will certainly add math.SE to the MathOverflow FAQ as soon as math.SE is public.

Answer (score 5):

I can start a thread on meta.MO (or add a new post to the old thread) that math.SE is in public beta (once that happens). However, I'm not sure that will be enough. For one thing, most of the people active on meta.MO are professional mathematicians.

Presumably many people active on SO will have heard about it.

Comment: That would be very helpful.  We really need some professional mathematicians here, even if they don't participate actively, but just skim over the questions from time to time, and pick the ones that are in their areas of expertise.

Comment: Please do! Professional mathematicians might also have lower-level questions in fields outside their area of expertise, and can certainly help to answer many of the questions here. At worst, let them be the ones to decide that they're not interested.

Comment: a related question: I remember seeing that there was a way to be a referrer for new users, and gain reputation. But I cannot find the relevant document anywhere. Did I dream of it?

Answer (score 2):

[This proposed faq answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/what-should-go-in-the-math-stackexchange-faq/108#108) mentions other math websites. Perhaps someone with a presence there can help promote this site.

Answer (score 2):

Hacker News. And post links to answers to interesting questions there.

We need to get it on slashdot too.

**Edit**
Not to sound elitist, but the best way to make this site successful would be to advertise to Math/Physics/Engineering majors at top schools.

Its what worked for Facebook.

Comment: Redditing would also be  a good idea (that site gets a lot of views).

Comment: This would be great when the site goes public. I think the other options are better for now.

Comment: Why, may I ask, would you go to the worst places on the internet and invite everyone to the party?  That seems really really really dangerous.

Comment: @97832123 I was trying to think of the most viral places, but I agree that they are not going to get the highest quality users. Ideally we should try to get math, physics, engineering majors from schools top schools, and then everyone else. I don't know how to do that though...

Comment: This is yet another thing that the mathematicians of MO could help us with.  The majority of them are involved in competitive programs around the world and likely have the trust and admiration of students at the level we are looking for.  Let's ask them for some word of mouth help.  I think there is nothing wrong with hitting Reddit and other sites **after this site is very well-established**.

Comment: @Tom Yeah, now that I am thinking more clearly I agree with you

Comment: @Jonathan: Surely almost everyone here knows a few people who are really good at maths

Comment: @9978: Better than 4chan

Comment: @Casebash no doubt. But that would be useful for the branding of the site. It would be useful for the site to have that association. Who is actually on the site could be different.

Answer (score 2):

I will publicize it on my own blog, even if it's in Italian and read by Italians :-)

Comment: If they start asking questions here in Italian, it will be your job to answer them then!

Comment: oh no, my job would be to translate them (and translate the answers back)!