# Show LaTeX syntax in "How to Format" box

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax

I think you need to show the syntax for LaTeX formatting in the "How to Format" box when writing a question or answer. I just mean showing how to surround in `$` or `$$`, not how to actually write LaTeX formulas. (But maybe there could be a link to an external LaTeX syntax help page too?)

**Edit** Something like suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it). Here's a mockup:

[image]

Comment: I suppose [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) could be edited appropriately.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Completed, but I said MathJaX instead of LaTeX -- that didn't seem correct to me.

I wasn't sure what to use as the "MathJax help" link; the [meta faq question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) is a bit out of date so I picked http://www.mathjax.org/demos/

Comment: Thank you, this is most helpful. Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) should also have at least some description of MathJax as well?

Comment: Thanks, the help box is almost perfect, but MathJax will render the `$\sin^2 \theta$` in it, so what the user actually sees is "MathJax equation sin² θ", which isn't correct. It has to be wrapped between `<code/>` tags or `<span class="tex2jax_ignore"/>` tags to avoid MathJax parsing it.

Comment: thanks Jeff, but as KennyTM points out, the sample MathJax actually gets rendered by MathJax, thus making it useless!

Comment: @Kip, @Kenny: looks to be fixed now. Thanks @Jeff (or whoever did the tweaking.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am currently trying to find out how to do this and can't. I am going to post an answer in raw format and hope that someone edits it for me :)

Comment: i'm not sure i understand... you're trying to find out how to do what? use latex in posts? the FAQ links to this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/what-should-go-in-the-math-stackexchange-faq/117#117

Comment: The links should be much, much more obvious, took me a while to see that.