# What should I do about answers/questions in other languages?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, languages

I stumped upon [this answer not in English by a new user](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2377280/356114). Using Google translates, it seems the user is answering some irrelevant stuffs, so I think it would be safe to down vote. But what should I do in general if I happen to see other answers not in English, but the answer is indeed relevant to the question? And what about a question not in English?

Comment: As you probably noticed in the list of related question on the right, questions in different languages have been discussed before. See [What is the site etiquette about (i) asking and (ii) answering questions in a language other than English?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1617) and perhaps also other posts [linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1617).

Comment: A Comment alerting a new user to the use of English by the Community is certainly a first step.  This is not peculiar to Math.SE.  While *questions* in another language may be remediated by appropriate translation (rationalized as helping users whose first language is not English express themselves as clearly as possible), the goal of curating content in English is primary.  Thus I think Answers should be posted in English from the start.

Comment: See the new FAQ: [What is Math SE's policy on posts in languages other than English?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35656)