# Common acronyms used on main and meta

Tags: support, faq, reference

When I first joined this site, I had to figure out “OP” from context. Finding out what “CW” means was much easier, as it is often spelled out in full. CFV I had to be point-blank told about. It seems that there ought to be an obvious and easily-accessible place of explanation for all acronyms used on this site and, for that matter, all the jargon used on this site, for things like “closed”, “dis-accepted”, and even for seemingly obvious things like “up-vote”, “down-vote”, and perhaps a candid list of hidden gottchas, like the silent no-warning 5-minute timeout on editing a comment.

It seems like it wouldn’t take much to have a drop-down list available on both main and meta, the text in the box being something like “click here for an explanation of ACRONYMS and jargon used on this site”. This drop-down box could be in the right-most column where currently tangential stuff (like questions from other sites) is currently displayed.

WDYT? (What do you think?)

Comment: Mia ekrano glaciiĝis kiam mi klakis sur ĝi.

Comment: Mi estas vere mizera aŭdi tion sed mi ne scias kion fari pri ĝi.

Comment: @Didier, CFV = call for votes, apparently.

Comment: As I've learned from Willie Wong's answer [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4090/what-does-op-mean/4091#4091), meta.SO has [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms), which contains some acronyms, too.

Comment: @MikeJones: translation for those of us just beginning our Esperanto studies?

Comment: This question is related to the points raised in http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12202/

Answer (score 83, accepted):

A community wiki post is in order, methinks. Actually, the meaning of most of these terms can be found by Searching the Fantastic Web, but here are some of them for your convenience:

> AFAICT - as far as I can tell
> AFAIK - as far as I know
> AKA - also known as
> BTW - by the way
> bump - doing something (e.g. editing) to a post so that it rises to the top of the list of posts
> CFD - call for discussion
> CFV - call for votes
> close - make a question no longer open for answers to be added
> CV - [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), the StackExchange site for statistics
> CW - [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740), like this post.
> DV - downvote
> EoQS - [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)
> FAQ - [frequently asked questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq)
> FGITW - [fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19533)
> FWIW - for what(ever) it's worth
> GIYF - Google is your friend
> [help vampire](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15140) - those who suck the life and energy out of generously helpful people by expecting others to do their work for them
> HNQ - hot network question
> HTH - hope this helps
> HW - homework
> IANA$\ast$ - I am not a(n) $\ast$, where $\ast$ is most often lawyer but on math.SE might be more often "algebraic geometer", "number theorist", "logician", etc.
> iff - if and only if
> IIRC - if I recall/remember correctly
> IM((V)H)O - in my ((very) humble) opinion
> IOW - in other words
> ISO - in search of
> LHF - low hanging fruit, questions that are (relatively) easy to answer
> LHS - left hand side
> LMGTFY - Let me google that for you
> main - (when used on Math SE) refers to [the main Math SE site](https://math.stackexchange.com)
> meta - (when used on Math SE) refers to [the meta site for Math SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com)
> MO - [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/), the research level uncle of MSE. Which brings us to...
> MSE - Math Stack Exchange (also sometimes referred to as MathSE, m.SE, M.SE, or math.SE) **or** [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) the meta-site for the entire Stack Exchange network (also known as meta.SE).
> MSO - [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) (also meta.SO), the discussion site associated with SO; which was used for SE network-wide discussions, bugs and feature requests before new [Meta Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/) was started.
> NARQ - not a real question; mostly used in connection with voting to close a question
> not an answer - not an answer to the stated question; typically used for very interesting content that is [too long for a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2134785)
> NSC - necessary and sufficient condition(s)
> NSFW - not safe for work
> OP - original post(er); whichever of the two meanings is intended is *usually* inferable from context.
> OTOH - on the other hand
> ping - notify using the [@-notification system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019) in comments
> PSQ - [Problem Statement Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33854/what-is-a-psq) (also [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9473/psq-and-the-faq)), aka [Please-Solve Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25547), a question whose body contains only the statement of a problem ("Prove that ..." or "Please Solve ...")
> reopen - make a closed question once again open for answers to be added
> RHS - right hand side
> QED - *Quod Erat Demonstrandum*, Latin for "which was to be demonstrated". Used to end a proof
> SE - Stack Exchange, the network of Q&A sites including this one. Sometimes used as *.SE to denote a particular site of this network (e.g. [physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), [stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/))
> SEDE - [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/)
> SO - [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), the oldest and largest site of the SE network
> s.t. - such that / subject to
> TFAE - The Following Are Equivalent.
> TLA - Three Letter Abbreviation
> [tl;dr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL;DR) - Too long; didn't read. Sometimes a dismissal; occasionally denotes a brief summary of a verbose post.
> vote - that is, upvote/downvote; the clicking of the arrows on the left of posts to show interest/agreement, or the opposite.
> WLOG - Without Loss Of Generality
> WRT - With respect to (used generally for differentiation and integration)
> WTS - want to show
> YMMV - your mileage may vary (I don't know how well this will work for you)
> +1/-1 - explicit indication that you upvoted or downvoted a post; indicates agreement/disagreement
> ∎ or $\square$ (square box, tombstone) - sometimes used in place of QED, q.v.
> ♦ identifies a moderator of the site

Everybody else: add to this post as you see fit.

Comment: A half loaf is better than none, so I have up-voted and accepted your answer.

Comment: I'm still inviting other people to edit this, to make a more-or-less usable dictionary.

Comment: I've never seen OP used to refer to a post, only to a poster. Also, I've always assumed +1/-1 is used to indicate "I have upvoted/downvoted this, because...", followed by a reason for the agreement/disagreement.

Comment: Like Rahul, I had never thought that OP could refer to the original post. But I like that interpretation. From this point on let's agree that when we criticize the OP, we are criticizing the post, not the poster. Makes for a friendlier site.

Comment: I had always thought of "+1" as an idiom. @Rahul's interpretation works for me, too. :)

Comment: @Rah In OP the O denotes original / opening and the P denotes poster / post. The latter (post) denotation is in use, e.g. see the Wikipedia [Internet forum page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_forum#Post)

Comment: And how about "lorem ipsum" as "nonsense text used for, among other things, satisfying a minimum character count"?

Comment: Oh @Gerry, you're such a kidder. :D Morally, I'd alphabetize, but it might break the joke...

Comment: Do we have to have the common ones, like btw, too? It makes the list more cluttered.

Comment: I would have gone to my grave thinking IANA meant "Internet Assigned Numbers Authority" only if it weren't for this post.

Comment: @GEdgar, see my comment to Gerry.

Comment: "QED" could also stand for "Quite Easily Done" :)

Comment: An example of correct usage: "IMO, IMO can be on MO."

Comment: Looks as if in an SE (= Stock Exchange)

Comment: Is there any "fastest gun in the west" problem discussion here in MSE meta?

Comment: @Shuhao, I don't remember a particular thread, but we (me certainly included) whine about it a lot various times in meta and in chat...

Comment: @Ｊ.M. Is there any correlation analysis based on "question upvote normalized by question upvote and view" vs time?

Comment: @Shuhao, none I can recall offhand, but it shouldn't be too hard to construct a data.SE query for that...

Answer (score 19):

Mathematical abbreviations:

- **AC** - the [axiom of choice](https://enwp.org/axiom_of_choice)
- **AGM** - arithmetic-geometric mean ([inequality](https://enwp.org/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) or [function](https://enwp.org/Arithmetic-geometric_mean))
- **BLT** - [bounded linear transformation theorem](https://enwp.org/BLT-theorem)
- **BMO** - a function with the [bounded mean oscillation property](https://enwp.org/Bounded_mean_oscillation), or the set of such functions
- **BVP** - [boundary value problem](https://enwp.org/boundary_value_problem)
- **cadlag** - [*continue à droite, limite à gauche*](https://enwp.org/cadlag) (right continuous with left limits)
- **CCC** - [countable chain condition](https://enwp.org/countable_chain_condition), [Cartesian closed category](https://enwp.org/cartesian_closed_category)
- **CDF** - [cumulative distribution function](https://enwp.org/cumulative_distribution_function)
- **CFG** - [context-free grammar](https://enwp.org/context-free_grammar)
- **CMT** - [continuous mapping theorem](https://enwp.org/Continuous_mapping_theorem) or [contraction mapping theorem](https://enwp.org/Contraction_mapping_theorem)
- **CNF** - [conjunctive normal form](https://enwp.org/conjunctive_normal_form)
- **CRT** - [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://enwp.org/Chinese_remainder_theorem)
- **DNF** - [disjunctive normal form](https://enwp.org/disjunctive_normal_form)
- **FEM** - [finite element method](https://enwp.org/finite_element_method)
- **FFT** - [fast Fourier transform](https://enwp.org/fast_Fourier_transform)
- **FLT** - [Fermat's last theorem](https://enwp.org/Fermat%27s_last_theorem), [Fermat's little theorem](https://enwp.org/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)
- **FOL** - [first-order logic](https://enwp.org/first-order_logic)
- **HOL** - [higher-order logic](https://enwp.org/higher-order_logic)
- **IFT** - [inverse function theorem](https://enwp.org/Inverse_function_theorem) or the equivalent [implicit function theorem](https://enwp.org/Implicit_function_theorem)
- **IVP** - [initial value problem](https://enwp.org/initial_value_problem)
- **KKT** - [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions](https://enwp.org/KKT_conditions)
- **LP** - [linear programming](https://enwp.org/linear_programming)
- **LHS** - [left hand side](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sides_of_an_equation)
- **LS** - [least squares](https://enwp.org/least_squares)
- **MCMC** -[Monté Carlo Markov Chain](https://enwp.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo)
- **MCT** - [monotone convergence theorem](https://enwp.org/monotone_convergence_theorem)
- **MLE** - [maximum likelihood estimator](https://enwp.org/maximum_likelihood_estimator)
- **MSE** - [mean squared error](https://enwp.org/Mean_squared_error)
- **NPC** - [$NP$-complete](https://enwp.org/NP-complete)
- **ODE** - [ordinary differential equation](https://enwp.org/ordinary_differential_equation)
- **PDE** - [partial differential equation](https://enwp.org/partial_differential_equation)
- **PDF** - [probability distribution function](https://enwp.org/probability_distribution_function)
- **PID** - [principal ideal domain](https://enwp.org/principal_ideal_domain)
- **RE** - [recursively enumerable](https://enwp.org/recursively_enumerable) language or set
- **(R)REF** - [(reduced) row echelon form](https://enwp.org/row_echelon_form)
- **RHS** - [right hand side](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sides_of_an_equation)
- **SDE** - [stochastic differential equation](https://enwp.org/Stochastic_differential_equation)
- **SOL** - [second-order logic](https://enwp.org/second-order_logic)
- **SVD** - [singular value decomposition](https://enwp.org/singular_value_decomposition)
- **UFD** - [unique factorization domain](https://enwp.org/unique_factorization_domain)
- **WKB** - [Wentzel–Kramers–Brillouin approximation/method](https://enwp.org/WKB_approximation)
- **ZF** - [Zermelo–Frankel set theory axioms](https://enwp.org/ZF_axioms), *without* the axiom of choice
- **ZFC** - [Zermelo–Frankel set theory axioms](https://enwp.org/ZF_axioms), *plus* the axiom of choice

This is *not* intended to be an enumeration of mathematical notation that happens to consist of capital letters, such as $\Bbb Z, SO(3),$ or $GF(8)$, but only commonly-appearing acronyms for specific English phrases.  Nor is it intended to be an exhaustive catalog of every abbreviation ever used. It should contain only the *most commonly-used* abbreviations.

Comment: It would be great if users tried to use acronyms sparingly and tried to spell them out at least once, especially when dealing with beginners. While REF or SVD may seem like perfectly obvious and common acronyms, it is very hard for a non-native speaker and non-expert to guess their meanings, especially if they are just starting out in linear algebra and had virtually no exposure to the technical terms in English. You might gain a few seconds by using the acronyms but 100 readers will lose a few minutes by deciphering them.

Comment: I agree with Martin. I'm not trying to recommend that any of these be used. Rather, I'm trying to document the abbreviations that *are* used, as an aid to people who don't recognize them.

Comment: I also agree with Martin.  I think the best way to help with understanding of acronyms is to try never to use them without first explaining them.  Most parts of mathematics are largely acronym-free, and I think this is commendable.  Conversely, I found it weird when all of a sudden multiple posts appeared on meta concerning "PSQ", as though it were obvious to all what that was supposed to be.  (Even after learning what P, S and Q stood for, the intended meaning was still not completely clear to me!)

Comment: Second order logic? In some communities, SOL is "Sod Out of Luck."

Comment: Wikipedia has a huge list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_abbreviations) (but it is missing e.g. BMO!)

Answer (score 5):

Here is the link to the similar list at the English Stack Exchange site:

https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147/list-of-common-abbreviations-noad-esl-pie

See it to find out what TPTB means:)