# Answering questions with a hint

Tags: discussion, closing, hint

Scenario: someone asks: "Let such-and-such. How do I prove X?". I answer "Hint: because blah, blah, blah, all you have to prove is Y". Their response is to ask a new question: "Let such-and-such. How do I prove Y?".

See 
[Proving a property of a Logic Formal Language](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199447/proving-a-property-of-a-logic-formal-language/1199597?noredirect=1#comment2441669_1199597)
and
[Proving some property of a Formal Logic Language](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199716/proving-some-property-of-a-formal-logic-language#comment2441910_1199716)
for the case in point. The potential infinite regress bottomed out because someone else answered the second question with more details on how to prove Y.

I voted to close the second question. Should I just give up answering questions with hints?

Comment: "I should just give up answering questions with hints." Yes. That.

Comment: I find this to be even more infuriating when the user accepts your answer. In general I find giving *good* hints to be a difficult task, which is sometimes harder than writing the complete solution. And I also feel that *good* hints are valuable in the future, for future readers. I truly understand your despair; but I think that hints are good, and if only because they help to drive away the people who refuse to think for themselves. (I know, there are a lot of bad things people do with hints, like lazy hints sometimes; but I wanted to highlight the good parts of hints.)

Comment: @Woodface: Why?

Comment: @Meelo: I've turned it into a specific question. What I wanted was advice about hints.

Comment: By the way, note the lovely post number on this question. Kudos! :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Good catch!

Comment: @Woodface I think answering with *good* hints is better than giving a solution, especially if the problem just needs some trick that you might not otherwise come up with.

Comment: I agree with @CameronWilliams - where a question is of the "homework/assignment" type, where it's the kind of question that gets asked in classes as a test of a student's understanding, good hints work best. The best hints help the person to understand the general concept of the approach, rather than spelling out the specifics - like explaining (x+y)^2 = (x+y)*(x+y) instead of spelling out the full process - spelling it out means the student is less likely to understand when it comes to doing (x+y+z)^2 or (x+y)^3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a number of ways that OP's might give an unsatisfactory response to a comment. I often say that they should do some trivial exercise which will show them what is going on; few try, and often enough someone gives a complete answer anyway. Some are like your guys, I think they are generically called Vampires on SE...

I probably used to try to get such people to improve. For a few years I've just been deleting my own comments or answers. I mostly cannot get the kids (sometimes older) asking to behave better, all i can do is make it so that I am not notified of further messages from that person.

one reference:

[Etiquette: How to deal with "spoon feeding" requests?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15139/etiquette-how-to-deal-with-spoon-feeding-requests/15140#15140)

which points to this  http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.