# How to deal with such new users?

Tags: discussion

In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269430/how-to-make-fxh-fx-h-for-fx-e2x-equal-to-the-fx-2e2x-a/2269432?noredirect=1#comment4667788_2269432) The user seems to be new to the fundamentals of calculus. I tried to give the answer as concisely and on-point as possible.   He had doubts regarding my answer so I tried to clear it by sending a link to the graph.

But how do I deal with users who tends to offer no regards too what the contributor is trying to explain and keep asking the same question again and again?

Yes I lost my temper and those CAPS (in the end) are clear signs to this. But I need some advice on how to deal with such users. Anyone?

Comment: Not exactly the same, but this seems at least a bit related: [Etiquette: How to deal with “spoon feeding” requests?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15139)

Comment: That user response looks a little bit strange to me. When I suspect someone is a .... I'll delete the answer (may or may not put the user on a blacklist) and moves on.

Comment: How do i blacklist a user? @achillehui

Comment: @TheDeadLegend I just mentally do that inside my brain. However, I do wish math.SE has such a feature.

Comment: @achillehui  I found that  I could not remember which usernames, among many similar, were the actual problem users, especially after time had passed. I simply made an ordinary text file on my home machine, each line would be the user profile url, some blank spaces, then the number of a question that would remind me of the nature of the problem. I named it idiots.txt

Comment: @WillJagy if the user is someone you can forget, then it is usually not that much of a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just delete your answer and leave.

Next time when you try to answer a question, first check if the questioner had provided enough information so that you are confident to give an answer that the questioner would understand. You may try to ask for more information in comment first, if there's no respond, voting to close as "missing contexts" is a much better options than providing a "concise" answer which the questioner do not understand.

For the question you linked, it turns out the questioner (after the lengthy exchanges between you and the questioner) still doesn't even understand why

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{2h} - 1} {2h} = 1$$

follows from

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}  =1.$$

The questioner has a poor understanding of limit.

Comment: Indeed,Doing so now