# type summation symbol in math.stackexchange

Tags: support, mathjax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FAQ for math.stackexchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange)

Suppose that I want to sum `p(xi)*log(p(xi))` from one to n. How can I type it using LaTeX? Please help me guys. I want to type it on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: `\sum_{i=1}^n p(x_i)\log p(x_i)` $\to \sum_{i=1}^n p(x_i)\log p(x_i)$.

Comment: if we want to use - sign?(minus)or for example  -1/2*log1/2-1/3*log/1/3?

Comment: it does not work

Comment: You have to surround math with dollar signs to have it render: `$\sum_{i=1}^n p(x_i)\log p(x_i)$`. Also, take a look at [How do I type math in my question/answer/comment?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) And it would help if you gave a little more information than just "it does not work".

Comment: If this question is due to [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95150/calculate-entropy-of-joined-distribution) here's why you had trouble: you shouldn't put blanks in front of the dollars (a line starting with four blanks gives a `code block`). The line containing the first formula was perfectly okay, up to those blanks.