# How to ensure that an active contest question is locked until the contest expires

Tags: support, contests, locked-posts

I answered the following question:

[4th Point Of A Rectangle - Co-Ordinate Geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743752/4th-point-of-a-rectangle-co-ordinate-geometry)

I then learned it was part of an active contest:

https://www.codechef.com/JULY20B/problems/PTMSSNG

I voted to close the question on the grounds that it should be locked until the contest was over.  It picked up some additional close votes, but it has not been locked despite receiving hundreds of additional views.  What reason should I give to ensure that an active contest question is locked?

I tried to delete my answer.  However, it had been accepted before I learned it was drawn from an active contest.  Since it was accepted, I could not delete my answer.

Comment: You could start by deleting your answer until the contest is over.  You can also be more cautious in the future before deciding to answer completely questions that you haven't searched to check if they are dupes, or contest problems.  But, ultimately, you've enabled this asker to cheat on an active contest problem.  So locking at this point in time won't undo your enabling.  Locking the post might prevent further users from cheating.

Comment: Also, as the question is a PSQ, you could have avoided helping a user cheat if you knew better than to answer PSQ's.

Comment: @amWhy  I tried to delete my answer.  However, it was accepted before I learned that it was drawn from an active contest.  Since it was accepted, I could not delete my answer

Comment: Yes, you are right, @N.F.Taussig.  I forgot about that issue.

Comment: Did you flag the question for moderator's attention - as recommended in the FAQ post on this issue: [“Contest problem” policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16774)?

Comment: @MartinSleziak  I believe I did.  I recall opening a dialogue box in which I stated the reason I was voting to close the question was that it was part of an active contest.  Thanks for voting to close the question.

Comment: @amWhy  Thanks for voting to close the question.

Comment: Worth noting:  The user in question posted more than one problem from that ongoing Codechef contest.  [The other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744040/intersection-of-plane-in-3d-cartesian-co-ordinate-geometry) is taken from https://www.codechef.com/JULY20B/problems/GEOXD.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig What you describe seems to me more like *voting to close* than flagging. Maybe you can check [in your flag summary](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current) whether you did flag the question. (My experience is that mods are relatively fast with handling contest question, I mean it might take hours, but not days.) In case my previous link dos not work, you can find the list of your flags [in the activity tab of your profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) when you click on the text "181 helpful flags".

Comment: @MartinSleziak  You are correct.  It appears I failed to flag the answer, which explains why this question went unnoticed for a week.

Answer (score 5):

In these situations please flag your answer, and we will take care of this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Do users who post questions from an active contest face penalties such as suspension or removal of their accounts?

Comment: @Batominovski: Sometimes, it depends if the account was created solely for cheating purposes, or things like that.

Comment: I hope that they at least get a warning from the moderators.

Answer (score 3):

Although it isn't as comprehensive in hiding the content as deleting would be, I've taken the liberty of editing ("defacing") the Accepted Answer.  Once the contest is over my edit can be rolled back (or sooner, if my approach doesn't meet with your approval).

Comment: It meets my approval.  Thank you.

Comment: This is a very smart work-around.