# Steps to avoid cheating in an International mathematics olympiad.

Tags: discussion, contests, help-center

First of all, I am sorry if the title doesn't make sense as I am posting after quite some time now. Feel free to change it if you can make it more informative.

I am part of the organising team of an International Mathematics Olympiad that is organised every year globally. Since the contest remain active for 12 hours chances are high that students may put the problems here on MSE in search of answers. I am looking to get in touch with people who can help me out to avoid such things from happening here on MSE. I know that such measures have been taken in the past for some contests.

I do not wish to reveal the name of the olympiad to avoid looking like a promotor but would like to mention that in the last edition 2500 people from all backgrounds and age groups participated in the Olympiad.

If this is not the appropriate platform to ask such questions then please let me know the right platform (any chat room or email address).

Thank you!

Comment: A relevant FAQ post: ["Contest problem" policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16774/915354)

Comment: @TheAmplitwist Thank you!

Comment: Some contest organizers have posted, to this site, a link to their contests. That way, users like me can know what the contest questions are, and can recognize them when someone posts them to the main site, and can then comment that the post comes from an active contest, can suggest that other users refrain from posting answers, and can report the post to the site moderators. A moderator can then close the post, so that no answers can be posted.

Comment: Do your participants take the test at home or in a supervised environment? If it is the first case, try requiring everyone to join in an online conference room and keep a camera pointed at their face. This way you still get to monitor your participants as if in a real test.

Comment: Care to engage with us, Vidyanshu?

Comment: Dear @LilyWhite this is not the case. They get the problem set at a specified time and a time period in which they have to open the problem set. Once they have access to the problems they have 12 hours to submit the solutions. The aim of the contest is to give everyone best possible problem solving experience but since there are good prizes also  it is our duty to take best possible measures to avoid cheating,

Comment: Dear @GerryMyerson if this is the case I can send the problem set to the most active people on the site when the contest starts. I will be grateful if you can tell me how to connect with active users like you.

Comment: I can't speak for other users, but you connect with me by posting here.

Comment: When the contest is over, let me know. Magnificently designed problems often bring  the best out of the population here, that's why I really love these competitions.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want a "sidebar" with the "most active people on the site", but read these points of the site's [Contest Problem Policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16774/915354):

- Publicly accessible source where we can verify that the question does come from a contest.
- Publicly accessible source where we can verify that the contest is currently on-going.

My approach would be to provide those links by editing your meta post here above.  Identifying the contest is necessary when it becomes public if you want the policy to apply, and it does not risk you "looking like a promotor".

Comment: From my time at the site, I know that Gerry is an active user so when he mentioned "users like me can know what the contest questions are, and can recognize them when someone posts them to the main site, and can then comment that the post comes from an active contest" I thought he meant active users like him. I am sorry for the misinterpretation. I will edit the post when the contest starts so that *users* can see the problems and take the necessary actions (I will also be active to do my part by flagging such problems if I see any).

Comment: Hello! This is off-topic but I do not know how else to ask you. Would you like to run for [moderator election on CompSci SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/election/3)? I think you will be a better candidate than most others, and I wouldn't want to see a lousy one elected just because nobody else ran for election. What do you think? =)

Comment: Hey there. I'm so glad I asked you, and congratulations on getting elected! =)